# .sql Dump Import with ERROR 1064 (42000) near '*/' at line 1

Tags: sql, import

I want to import a file that I received from a customer into my test DB.

I got a lot of errors so I decided to use the same system and database version as our customer.

But I still got the same problem...

The first SQL part is from the importfile where I have the problems:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `bm_adressen`
--

LOCK TABLES `bm_adressen` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bm_adressen` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `bm_adressen` VALUES (xxxxx);
INSERT INTO `bm_adressen` VALUES (xxx);
INSERT INTO `bm_adressen` VALUES (xxx);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bm_adressen` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ; 
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ; 
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ; 
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8mb4 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8mb4_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ; 
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/
/*!50017 DEFINER=`xadminer`@`localhost`*/
/*!50003 TRIGGER `bm_adressen_bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `bm_adressen` FOR EACH ROW
```

The last line creates the problems.

Any ideas?

Greetings, Robert

Comment: Could you correct grammar in your question? It's hard to read it.

Comment: typically, `/* */` cannot be used for comments in SQL dialects, only `--`.

Comment: ... what can i do? Should be i ask for e new SQL Dump?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.25                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1           |
| version                 | 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> STATUS;
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          19
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.10.2 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 15 hours 20 min 31 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 116  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 118  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 108  Queries per second avg: 0.002
--------------
```

When i import a .sql File, i get that Error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 166: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*/' at line 1